# $6 \geq \frac{a^2 +ab +2a+b^2 +3}{a^2+ab -2a +b^2 +3} + \frac{c^2 +cb +2b+b^2 +3}{c^2+cb-2a+b^2+3} + \frac{a^2+ac+2c+c^2 +3}{a^2+ac-2c +c^2 +3}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

I state the question again,
$$6 \geq \frac{a^2 +ab +2a+b^2 +3}{a^2+ab -2a +b^2 +3} + \frac{c^2 +cb +2b+b^2 +3}{c^2+cb-2b+b^2+3} + \frac{a^2+ac+2c+c^2 +3}{a^2+ac-2c +c^2 +3}$$
for $a,b,c \geq 1$

So far I've tried simplifying this down to
$$ 3 \geq \frac{4a}{a^2+ab -2a +b^2 +3} + \frac{4b}{c^2+cb-2b+b^2+3} + \frac{4c}{a^2+ac-2c +c^2 +3}
$$
But I'm not sure if this will do me any good. Any help is appreciated.

PS. I was told (by a friend so not 100%) that holder inequality may help here.

Comment: BW kills it, but it's ugly.

Comment: Yes that does answer my question. Thank you. @MichaelRozenberg I'm not sure what BW stands for?

Comment: see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h522084